# Suggestions to improve R-shiny code (Should I be running the code twice to plot different results in R-Shiny?)

Tags: r, shiny

I am fairly new to R-Shiny and I am trying to use a code I wrote in R with R-Shiny. Since the code was first written in R, I am facing difficulties with the syntax to be used in R-Shiny.

I want to know if there is a more efficient way where I don't have to write the entire code over again to plot different results.

For example, the format of my R-Shiny is in this manner:

```
ui <- fluidPage(


#my input Buttons/sliders( ),

#output functions (I am using 3 outputs)

plotOutput("Hindcast"),
plotOutput("Histogram"),
plotOutput("Pval")

)

server<-function(input,output) {

output$Hindcast<-renderPlot({

#Here I write my code

plot(#required output for "Hindcast")

})

output$Histogram <- renderPlot({

#Here I am required to write most of the code again
#I tried using the reactive function, but the way my code is built, it would 
require too many reactive functions

plot...
})
output$Pval <- renderPlot({

#entire code again

plot...
}) 
shinyApp(ui=ui, server)
```

I would have uploaded my code here but it's too long and the problem is not with the coding but the syntax.

Help appreciated.

Comment: if it fits within a `renderPlot()` it should fit within a reactive as well,..Whe way you ask your question it might be better suited for the codeReview site,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to definitively comment without the actual code but here is a link to some good resources on reactive programming.

https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/

The first 2 videos are a goldmine.

---

In general, you should never have any repetitive code in your app. And I dont see why you would require multiple reactive functions when your original app has repetitive code.

The first step to planning any app out is to have in mind (or on paper) the reactive dependancies present, ie. what `inputs` are my `outputs` dependant on.

Second, consider the question "what code is common to all the plots?". Since there are multiple plots the basic assumption is that something must change to generate the different plots. We take all the code before this point and we can call it the "shared code".

Lastly, we combine the first two points ensuring dependencies are preserved without having redundant code.

Here is a simple example with redundant code.

#### Redundant code

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

data = mtcars

shinyApp(ui = {
  fluidPage(
    sliderInput("selectHP","Select Horse Power",min(data$hp),max(data$hp),data$hp),
    sliderInput("selectCyl","Select Cylinders",min(data$cyl),max(data$cyl),data$cyl),
    sliderInput("mpg","Select MPG Range",min(data$mpg),max(data$mpg),data$mpg),
    plotOutput("hp_mpg"),
    plotOutput("cyl_mpg")
  )
},
server = function(input,output){
  output$hp_mpg = renderPlot({

    #Shared Code
    data = data%>%
      filter(between(hp,input$selectHP[1],input$selectHP[2]))%>%
      filter(between(cyl,input$selectCyl[1],input$selectCyl[2]))%>%
      filter(between(mpg,input$mpg[1],input$mpg[2]))

    plot(data$hp,data$mpg)
  })

  output$cyl_mpg = renderPlot({

    #Shared Code
    data = data%>%
      filter(between(hp,input$selectHP[1],input$selectHP[2]))%>%
      filter(between(cyl,input$selectCyl[1],input$selectCyl[2]))%>%
      filter(between(mpg,input$mpg[1],input$mpg[2]))

    plot(data$hp,data$cyl)
  })
})
```

#### Redundancy removed

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

data = mtcars

shinyApp(ui = {
  fluidPage(
    sliderInput("selectHP","Select Horse Power",min(data$hp),max(data$hp),data$hp),
    sliderInput("selectCyl","Select Cylinders",min(data$cyl),max(data$cyl),data$cyl),
    sliderInput("mpg","Select MPG Range",min(data$mpg),max(data$mpg),data$mpg),
    plotOutput("hp_mpg"),
    plotOutput("cyl_mpg")
  )
},
server = function(input,output){


  data_reactive = reactive({
    data = data%>%
      filter(between(hp,input$selectHP[1],input$selectHP[2]))%>%
      filter(between(cyl,input$selectCyl[1],input$selectCyl[2]))%>%
      filter(between(mpg,input$mpg[1],input$mpg[2]))

    return(data)
  })

  output$hp_mpg = renderPlot({

    plot(data_reactive()$hp,data_reactive()$mpg)
  })

  output$cyl_mpg = renderPlot({

    plot(data_reactive()$hp,data_reactive()$cyl)
  })
})
```